# Getting a reference to the text box elements on an edit

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

In my MVC grid, I'm trapping the Edit event as follows:

```
 .Events(events => events.Change("gridRowChange").Edit("onEdit"))
```

In my onEdit() method that gets called when an edit is occurring, I'd like to get a reference to the text box elements for each editable cell in the row so that I can attach an onBlur event to some of them. How do I go about getting a reference to each text box element in the row being edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Telerik's documentation for [OnEdit](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnEdit):

> The event argument exposes three fields:
>   dataItem - the JavaScript object to which the editor row is bound to. It is undefined during insertion.
>   mode - a string whose value is either "insert" or "edit"
>   form - the  DOM element which contains all editing components (textboxes, checkboxes, dropdownlists etc.)

This should get you a reference to a given textbox:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var yourTextBox = $(form).find("#your_id");

    yourTextBox.on("blur", function () {
        //your on blur code here
    });
}
```